# Remove Row Index dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a df

```
in[0]df1
out[0]
        DATE    REVENUE    COST    POSITION
FACTOR
0    2017/01/01    1000    900    10
1    2017/01/01    900     700    9
2    2017/01/01    1100    800    7
```

I have an additional row `FACTOR`. After trying `reset_index()` and other ways, I cannot remove the `FACTOR` multi (row) index. Is there a way to do so?

I know it's common to drop columns and reset index but not this way though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I hope this works :)

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True) # Resets the index, makes factor a column
df.drop("Factor",axis=1,inplace=True) # drop factor from axis 1 and make changes permanent by inplace=True
```

Answer (score 12):

Try using:

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This resets the index to the default integer index and removes the original one.
If you want to assign this change to original `dataframe` it is easier to use:

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

As it will edit the `df1` dataframe without making a copy of it.

Answer (score 6):

`FACTOR` is the name of the index - you shouldn't worry about it - it doesn't affect your data:

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
              DATE  REVENUE  COST  POSITION
FACTOR
10      2017/01/01     1000   900        10
11      2017/01/01      900   700         9
12      2017/01/01     1100   800         7

In [79]: df.index.name
Out[79]: 'FACTOR'
```

If you want to rename it or to get rid of it (preserving the index values) you can use [DataFrame.rename_axis()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) method:

```
In [80]: df = df.rename_axis(None)

In [81]: df
Out[81]:
          DATE  REVENUE  COST  POSITION
10  2017/01/01     1000   900        10
11  2017/01/01      900   700         9
12  2017/01/01     1100   800         7

In [82]: df.index.name is None
Out[82]: True
```