# How to remove extra row after set_index() without losing index name?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change my DataFrame index column with the `df.set_index()` function. While this provides a functional solution, it creates an "extra" row that I would like to get rid of.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c'], 'B': ['d','e','f'], 'C': [1,2,3]})
```

`df` looks like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  d  1
1  b  e  2
2  c  f  3
```

Changing the DataFrame index:

```
df.set_index('C')
```

Result:

```
   A  B
C
1  a  e
2  b  f
3  c  g
```

How can I make the dataframe look as follows?

```
C  A  B
1  a  e
2  b  f
3  c  g
```

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716402/remove-row-index-dataframe-pandas) but the solution using `reset_index()` did not provide the desired result. I would like to keep the values I have on column `C` and only remove the extra row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have `C` column as **index**:

```
In [50]: r = df.set_index('C')

In [51]: r
Out[51]:
   A  B
C
1  a  d
2  b  e
3  c  f

In [52]: r.index.name
Out[52]: 'C'

In [53]: r.columns.name is None
Out[53]: True

In [54]: r = r.rename_axis(None,0).rename_axis('C',1)

In [57]: r
Out[57]:
C  A  B
1  a  d
2  b  e
3  c  f

In [55]: r.index.name is None
Out[55]: True

In [56]: r.columns.name
Out[56]: 'C'
```

NOTE: but it looks pretty misleading...

Comment: that is a neat solution too.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you! But i think one should avoid doing such cosmetic things...

Comment: @MaxU Works perfectly, thanks for the answer! Btw, the result of rename_axis() has to be assigned to a new dataframe for it to work. Seems quite strange to me, but calling r after renaming produces the old result.

Comment: @MapleSyrup, yeah, most Pandas functions/methods don't change DF in place - they return a changed DF...

Comment: @MaxU Certainly seems so. I'm new to pandas and this behaviour is quite unintuitive...

Answer (score 3):

Try this with `[[]]`:

```
df[['C','A','B']]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c'], 'B': ['d','e','f'], 'C': [1,2,3]})
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  a  d  1
1  b  e  2
2  c  f  3

df = df[['C','A','B']]
print(df)

   C  A  B
0  1  a  d
1  2  b  e
2  3  c  f
```

Comment: A more canonical version for n columns = `df[c[-1:] + c[:-1]]` where `c = df.columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the `DataFrame` show(print) as what you want ...

```
print (df[['C','A','B']].to_string(index=False))
C  A  B
1  a  d
2  b  e
3  c  f
```